# Custom keyboard in swift iOS 10

Tags: swift

How do I create outlets for my keys in a custom keyboard to switch from letters to numbers and symbols? I am trying to create a custom keyboard and I don't know how to create outlets for my keys to switch back and forth from letters to numerals and symbols.

Comment: The iOS keyboard is a delegated (generally by  UITextField) view, that has properties which can switch its input, by setting a property of its delegate, like this: myTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.numberPad (for example). That's how you set the type of keyboard; switching back and forth seems like a lot of unnecessary work, but if you want to try, you should narrow your question a bit.

Comment: I want to set a button like the ABC/123 button to switch between the letters And numbers. How do I go about that?

Answer (score 0):

So, I gather from your comment, that this is what you are looking for. The type of keyboard input, is determined by setting the 'keyboardType' property of the keyboard's delegate. If you want to switch and update a view, I think you'll have to dismiss the keyboard and recall it. I find this unsafe, and would highly suggest using a normal keyboard (which has all the characters you need), trusting your user, and sanitizing the input. But the following does work, if you must. In the following, 'txtField' is a UITextField with the UIViewController set as its delegate, the IBAction is wired to a UIButton, and 'isNumbers' is a Bool property of the UIViewController.

```
@IBAction func switchKeyboards(_ sender: Any) {
    if isNumbers {
        txtField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.alphabet
        isNumbers = false
    } else {
        txtField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.numberPad
        isNumbers = true
    }
    txtField.resignFirstResponder()
    txtField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try it out.